# iOS scheme goes missing when I branch my project (Xcode 4.2)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

In Xcode 4.2 when I create a new branch and open it, the iOS scheme which exists in the Master is lost. Instead I have a scheme for 'Mac 64 bit."

This has happened a few times in a row and I handle it by creating a new scheme, deleting the 'Mac 64 bit' one and then renaming the new scheme to what the original was. I'd rather fix whatever is wrong though. Did I set something up wrong - some preference somewhere?

Answer (score 26):

I know this is old question but there doesn't seem to be a good question lately either.  So, I am adding my solution for this.

The issue is because the scheme is not checked into other branch.  If they are not, scheme will disappear on others.

If you wonder why this was not checked in, scheme is local unless you '**Check to Share**' box in **Manage Scheme** and source  controlled to git.

After it is saved in a branch, to make this change visible in other branches, you need to propagate this to the rest of working branches.

I did this using git command line because doing this xcode isn't so reliable because it is under .xcodeproj.

Comment: This was a bug in Xcode 4.x. You'd have to close and reopen the project after any external process (like git) modified the `.xcodeproj`. This is fixed in Xcode 5 and later.

Comment: this happened on Xcode 6 too.  Anyway, I agree restarting is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue and this is how I fixed it:

- From my master branch, I exported the schemes I needed - I did by navigating to `Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes...` on the Xcode menu. I then selected the schemes I wanted to export (i.e. `Development` and `Release` in my case). Finally, I chose the `Export...` option after clicking on the gear icon as shown in the picture below.

[image: Manage Scheme]

- Then I switched to my branch and followed the same steps as before but choosing `import` instead of `export`. And voila

Hope it helps! Cheers