# creating new branch does not reflect all the targets in Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, git, target, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm really now sure what is going wrong while creating a new branch for a particular feature using Sourcetree and Git.

I'm using Xcode 10 and creating a new branch called "Customer Gesture" from another branch "Gesture". I'm able to create it without any errors.

Now the when I checkout Branch "Customer Gesture" I do not see all the targets which are there when I checkout branch "Gesture".

I have attached the images for reference.

[image: Target from Gesture Branch]

[image: Target from Custom Gesture Branch]

really not sure where I could be wrong ??

Comment: Maybe this question is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9950259/2399348